# How do I limit the number of Jquery clones?

Tags: jquery, clone

I am trying to limit the number of clones on the following link :

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/63BV7/2/)

This is the Jquery codeing:

```
$("#addbt").click(function () {
 $('#choice').clone()
     .attr('id', 'choice' + $('.ddl').length)
     .attr('name', 'choice' + $('.ddl').length)
     .insertAfter(".ddl:last");
 $('#num').clone()
     .attr('id', 'num' + $('.dd2').length)
     .attr('name', 'num' + $('.dd2').length)
     .insertAfter(".dd2:last");});

 $("#removebt").click(function () {
   $("#choice1").remove();
   $("#num1").remove();
 });
```

I placed it on JSFiddle so everyone can see its current functional coding.

Comment: Check the `$('.ddl').length` each time, and prevent the `clone()` if the result is greater than the number you want to limit it to?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#addbt").click(function () {

   // check count
   var clonedCount = $('[id^=choice]').length; // OR $('.ddl').length @Matt mentioned

   if( clonedCount >  3) return false;   // stop clonning

   $('#choice').clone()
        .attr('id', 'choice' + $('.ddl').length)
        .attr('name', 'choice' + $('.ddl').length)
        .insertAfter(".ddl:last");
    $('#num').clone()
        .attr('id', 'num' + $('.dd2').length)
        .attr('name', 'num' + $('.dd2').length)
        .insertAfter(".dd2:last");
});
```

[*JSFiddle Link*](http://jsfiddle.net/63BV7/6/)